# Deleting parts from a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a very long nested list. Here is a short example:

```
list = {{1.2, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}, {0.9, {3, 3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4}}, {1.4, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {5, 5, 5}}}
```

Now I want to cancel all entries if the first entry of each part of the list (`list[[i]]`) is > 1. So that the new list would only consist of the second part of list (`list[[2]]`)

```
newlist = {0.9, {3, 3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4}}
```

I have already tried my luck with `Position` and `Delete`, but with no success.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: `Cases[list, {x_?NumericQ, a__} /; x <= 1 -> {x, a}]`

Comment: It works great. Thanks a lot

Comment: This is a very common type of question.  (I may close it as a duplicate.)  I agree with Pinguin Dirk's use of `Pick`, e.g. my own answers to [(900)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/900/121) and  [(30155)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30155/121)

Comment: @belisarius That's too complicated; you need merely this: `Cases[list, {x_, a__} /; x <= 1]`.  Also don't forget to use `:>` with named patterns!

Comment: I believe that the output you are looking for is a sublist of `list`, it should therefore be `{{0.9, {3, 3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4}}}` (note the extra `{}`) -- Unless you know that only one item will be selected.

Comment: `DeleteCases[list, {a_, __List} /; a > 1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than think of it as deleting certain unwanted parts of the list, you can equivalently think of it as selecting the parts you wish to keep. Accordingly, `Select` can be straightforwardly applied

```
Select[list, #[[1]] < 1 &]
{{0.9, {3, 3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4}}}
```

A. G. points out that this can be made more transparent by replacing the perhaps somewhat cryptic `Part` command `[[1]]` with

```
Select[list, First[#] < 1 &]
```

You can `Flatten[%, 1]` if you wish to get the levels exactly as described in the question.

Comment: Note that `#[[1]]` can also be written `First[#]` or `First@#` or even `(# // First)` !!!

Answer (score 3):

A solution using `Pick`:

```
Pick[list, UnitStep[list[[All, 1]] - 1], 0]
```

(I subtract one from the first element and then grab all positions with a negative such element)

Comment: Great idea. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{1.2, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}},
        {0.9, {3, 3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4}},
        {1.4, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {5, 5, 5}}};
```

---

Using `Replace`:

```
Replace[list, {a_ /; a > 1, ___} :> Nothing, {1}]

(*{{0.9, {3, 3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4}}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = 
 {{1.2, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}, 
  {0.9, {3, 3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4}}, 
  {1.4, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {5, 5, 5}}};
```

via `Position`

```
p = Position[list, {x_ /; x > 1, __}, 1]
```

{{1}, {3}}

Using `Delete`

```
Delete[p] @ list
```

{{0.9, {3, 3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4}}}

Using `ReplaceAt` (new in 13.1)

```
ReplaceAt[_ :> Nothing, p] @ list
```

{{0.9, {3, 3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4}}}

Answer (score 1):

**Using `Sow`/`Reap`:**

```
list = {{1.2, {1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}}, {0.9, {3, 3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 
    4}}, {1.4, {4, 4, 4, 4}, {5, 5, 5}}}

Scan[
    If[First@# < 1, Sow@#, Nothing] &
    , list] //
   Reap // Last // First
```

---

> {{0.9, {3, 3, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 4}}}