# How to keep elements only if their first key is part of another list?

Tags: filtering

I have two huge lists: `list1` and `list2`.

I would like to keep elements of `list1`, only if their first key is part of `list2`.

Example:

```
list1 = {{aa, 2, 5}, {be, 1, 5}, {ce, 5, 2}, {de, 1, 20}, {ee, 5, 2}}

list2 = {aa, ce, de}
```

Expected resulted:

```
list1 = {{aa, 2, 5}, {ce, 5, 2}, {de, 1, 20}}
```

I tried [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html), but I couldn't find a way. I think I have to look for a pattern that says "Pick element only if element belongs to `list2`"? What could it be?

My lists are very large so I can't do it manually.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: related: [69299](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69299/5478), duplicate: [30155](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30155/5478)

Comment: How "huge" is "huge"? None of the answers so far is particularly fast on "huge" lists (i.e., they can b beaten by order of magnitude +) - please specify cardinality expected of each list, key universe, etc...

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for finding a duplicate!

Comment: @ciao: list 1 has dimensions {2866206,3} and list 2 {100221,1}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some additional methods

```
list1 = {{aa, 2, 5}, {be, 1, 5}, {ce, 5, 2}, {de, 1, 20}, {ee, 5, 2}};

list2 = {aa, ce, de};

Select[list1, MemberQ[list2, #[[1]]] &]
```

> {{aa, 2, 5}, {ce, 5, 2}, {de, 1, 20}}

```
Cases[list1, _?(MemberQ[list2, #[[1]]] &)]
```

> {{aa, 2, 5}, {ce, 5, 2}, {de, 1, 20}}

```
Pick[list1, MemberQ[list2, #[[1]]] & /@ list1]
```

> {{aa, 2, 5}, {ce, 5, 2}, {de, 1, 20}}

```
DeleteCases[list1, _?(! MemberQ[list2, #[[1]]] &)]
```

> {{aa, 2, 5}, {ce, 5, 2}, {de, 1, 20}}

```
DeleteCases[list1, _?(FreeQ[list2, #[[1]]] &)]
```

> {{aa, 2, 5}, {ce, 5, 2}, {de, 1, 20}}

Comment: Thank you very much @bob hanlon!!

Answer (score 1):

```
Select[list1, MemberQ[list2, #[[1]]] &]
```